# Spring Data Elasticsearch "Error creating elasticsearchTemplate"

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Im using:

- elasticsearch 5.4.
- Spring boot 1.4.7.RELEASE
- spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.1.RELEASE.

  @Configuration
  @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.landfiles.farms.repository")
  public class ESConfig {

  @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
  private String EsHost;

  @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
  private Integer EsPort;

  @Bean
  public Client client() throws Exception {
  return new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
  InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
  }

  @Bean
  public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
  return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
  }
  }

I have a fail on the application run:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/model/Property
```

Full stackstrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/model/Property
```

Jira's issue linked (not answered) : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/939 (formerly DATAES-364)

Anybody have a working hello world example ?

Thanks!